# Asp.net MVC4 Storing sensitive user data

Tags: c#, session, cookies, asp.net-mvc-4, memcached

I have a Asp.Net MVC4 website which can connect to multiple databases depending on the user's login credentials. In order to get the database access list for the user, I have to perform a few complex joins when they login. To avoid having to do this more than once, I am currently encrypting and storing the database ID in a cookie. I now realize that this may not be a good idea and even strong encryption may be broken. In addition, the encrypted cookie is transferred around on every request increasing traffic. I am now thinking about using the HttpContext.Current.Cache to store the data instead. Can anyone comment on whether this is a good idea. I would also be interested in knowing if there are better options out there. My website is not deployed on a server farm right now but what would be the implications if I were to use a cache and a server farm in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements (i.e. keep a hold of sensitive user specific info across a session), the correct place is for this is the [SessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). AFAIK sessions states can be shared across multiple web servers so if you did use a server farm you wouldn't need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Session is right container for user sensitive data. Or you can store it in database and get it there by some identifier that is stored in session(it is useful if you store large amount of data).

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I thought of but I wanted a second opinion to make sure I did not have to recode my application. Do you know how I can get session to work if the website is deployed in a server farm.